# Installing APT via dpkg causes ldconfig not found in path error

Tags: linux, apt, path, dpkg

The situation began with an issue preventing me from updating, upgrading, or installing anything using apt. In an attempt to resolve this, I utilized dpkg to remove apt and then sought to reinstall it through the .deb file. Unfortunately, this approach did not yield the expected results, leading to the error depicted in the screenshot provided below:

[Error when installing .deb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVGTO.png)

Upon researching the problem on Google, I only discovered solutions recommending the installation of a package called glibc-source via apt. This advice proved unhelpful as I no longer had apt on my system.

Currently, I am unable to access the VPS via SSH, encountering a "Connection Refused" error. Consequently, I must utilize the web console VNC Rescue mode from zap-hosting.com to gain entry into the system.

Comment: Do not post images where plain text will do.

Comment: Either you have broken your system, changed your path not to include `/sbin`, or you have deleted `/sbin/ldconfig`. That file is part of glibc which you are unlikely to have deleted. You have no reason to install `glibc-source`.

Comment: my path variable contains following: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: You need to download the package `libc-bin` from a reliable package source and install it. After installation do `dpkg-reconfigure libc-bin` to make sure everything is correct

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc-bin:
libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.38); however; version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.38-4